# Javascript Recursive Backtracking Sudoku Solver

Tags: javascript, backtracking, sudoku, recursive-backtracking

I recently wrote this same code in Golang with some help from here.

If you are familiar with go you can see the working code here.

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OxKk7HPunCs)

Here is what I am trying to accomplish in python.
[Computerphile Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM&t=498s)

I am now trying to port this to javascript.

I initialize the gameState.

```
var gameState = [
    [5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
    [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
    [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]
]
```

This is the grid taken from the sudoku Wikipedia page.

[Sudoku Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku)

I wrote the following helper functions to get the row, column and block units of anywhere on the grid. I've tested them all and they all seem to work fine.

```
function isUnitUnique(unit) {
    for (let value = 1; value <= 9; value++) {
        let tally = 0;
        for (let index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
            if (unit[index] == value) {
                tally++;
            }
        }
        if (tally > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function getColumnUnit(board, column) {
    let unit = [];
    for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        unit.push(board[row][column]);
    }
    return unit;
}
function getBlockUnit(board, x, y) {
    let unit = []
    if (x >= 0 && x <= 2) { j = 1; }
    else if (x >= 3 && x <= 5) { j = 4; }
    else if (x >= 6 && x <= 8) { j = 7; }
    if (y >= 0 && y <= 2) { i = 1; }
    else if (y >= 3 && y <= 5) { i = 4; }
    else if (y >= 6 && y <= 8) { i = 7; }
    unit.push(board[i - 1][j - 1]);
    unit.push(board[i - 1][j]);
    unit.push(board[i - 1][j + 1]);
    unit.push(board[i][j - 1]);
    unit.push(board[i][j]);
    unit.push(board[i][j + 1]);
    unit.push(board[i + 1][j - 1]);
    unit.push(board[i + 1][j]);
    unit.push(board[i + 1][j + 1]);
    return unit;
}
```

I then use the helper functions with the following code to try and solve the puzzle. This is a recursive backtracking algorithm.

```
function solve() {
    for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (let column = 0; column < 9; column++) {
            if (gameState[row][column] == 0) {
                for (let value = 1; value <= 9; value++) {
                    if (possible(row, column, value)) {
                        gameState[row][column] = value;
                        solve();
                        gameState[row][column] = 0;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(gameState);
    return;
}
function possible(y, x, n) {
    let boardCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(gameState));
    boardCopy[y][x] = n;
    return isUnitUnique(boardCopy[y]) && isUnitUnique(getColumnUnit(boardCopy, x)) && isUnitUnique(getBlockUnit(boardCopy, x, y))
}
```

This console logs the initial game state unchanged. From doing some debugging I can see that the algorithm is going through the grid however it doesn't seem to keep the changes that I make to the grid.

Thanks in advance.

As suggested here is a runnable version of my code. It works when I run it in the snippet. When using chrome it doesn't.

```js
var gameState = [
    [5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
    [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
    [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]
]
function solve() {
    for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (let column = 0; column < 9; column++) {
            if (gameState[row][column] == 0) {
                for (let value = 1; value <= 9; value++) {
                    if (possible(row, column, value)) {
                        gameState[row][column] = value;
                        solve();
                        gameState[row][column] = 0;
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(gameState);
    return;
}
function possible(y, x, n) {
    let boardCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(gameState));
    boardCopy[y][x] = n;
    return isUnitUnique(boardCopy[y]) && isUnitUnique(getColumnUnit(boardCopy, x)) && isUnitUnique(getBlockUnit(boardCopy, x, y))
}
function isUnitUnique(unit) {
    for (let value = 1; value <= 9; value++) {
        let tally = 0;
        for (let index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
            if (unit[index] == value) {
                tally++;
            }
        }
        if (tally > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function getColumnUnit(board, column) {
    let unit = [];
    for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        unit.push(board[row][column]);
    }
    return unit;
}
function getBlockUnit(board, x, y) {
    let unit = []
    if (x >= 0 && x <= 2) { j = 1; }
    else if (x >= 3 && x <= 5) { j = 4; }
    else if (x >= 6 && x <= 8) { j = 7; }
    if (y >= 0 && y <= 2) { i = 1; }
    else if (y >= 3 && y <= 5) { i = 4; }
    else if (y >= 6 && y <= 8) { i = 7; }
    unit.push(board[i - 1][j - 1]);
    unit.push(board[i - 1][j]);
    unit.push(board[i - 1][j + 1]);
    unit.push(board[i][j - 1]);
    unit.push(board[i][j]);
    unit.push(board[i][j + 1]);
    unit.push(board[i + 1][j - 1]);
    unit.push(board[i + 1][j]);
    unit.push(board[i + 1][j + 1]);
    return unit;
}
solve()
```

Comment: What is this line `gameState[row][column] = 0;` supposed to do?

Comment: I see, that is part of the backtracking. What happens when it reaches the answer though, isn't it going to zero out everything on the way back out?

Comment: @bcr666 When it calls solve() directly above that it enters the function with the game state updated to the new potential variable. It keeps doing this until reaches a point where there are no valid values (1-9) and it hits the first return statement. This then reenters the function from prior and changes the value to zero, as the value it was before couldn't find a solution. Eventually, it gets to a point where there are no more cases of 0 values on the grid, it exits the for loops and outputs the grid. I'll add a youtube video that shows it being done in python.

Comment: Go links, YouTube videos of Python, Wikipedia links... What's missing is a [mre] which shows the code in action, including the part where it's not working. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create something that runs her on Stack Overflow so people don't need to go to other sites to figure out your question. Thanks.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the advice. I added a stack snippet of the code. Interestingly enough it runs and produces the expected output. I wonder why it doesn't locally on my VS Code / chrome environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @HereticMonkey for suggesting I use stack snippets to share my code. In doing so I realized that it worked in this environment, and that it had to do with running the code in the browser that was causing the issue (Chrome). Also thanks to @bcr666 who also mentioned that potentially the algorithm was zeroing itself out on the way back.

The code listed in the question was all correct. I added one check to prevent the function from continuing to execute after it reached its exit condition.

```
let solved = false
function solve() {
    for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (let column = 0; column < 9; column++) {
            if (gameState[row][column] == 0) {
                for (let value = 1; value <= 9; value++) {
                    if (possible(row, column, value)) {
                        gameState[row][column] = value;
                        solve();
                        if (!solved) {
                            gameState[row][column] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    solved = true;
    console.log(gameState);
    return;
}
```

Checking if the game has been solved before backtracking fixed this issue. Before it would log the results it was attempting to find more solutions.